# When do I need to use layoutInDisplayCutoutMode?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Android added a way to deal with devices that have a notch/cutout at the top of the screen. (See [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#layoutInDisplayCutoutMode) and [Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/pie#display-cutout-support).) But as far as I can tell, Android automatically takes care of lowering the views so that they aren't obscured by the notch, so why do we need this new addition?

I tested my Android app on the emulator of a device with a notch and the app *automatically* goes below the notch without the need to specify [layoutInDisplayCutoutMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#layoutInDisplayCutoutMode) as [LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER).

So my question is, when *would* I need to use `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER`?

In [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/pie#new-features) that would be:

```
Window.Attributes.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = Android.Views.LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode.Never;
```

I'm running this on the Android Emulator through Visual Studio on a Windows computer. The emulator is emulating a Pixel 3 XL with Android Pie 9.0 (API 28). The app is an Android app created with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @About Android 9 Pie has added a new LayoutInDisplayCutoutMode window layout attribute, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/pie

Comment: CherryBu-MSFT - You just linked to the page I had already linked to, and not even to the appropriate place on the page (which I did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating a view, which uses full screen for showing content at that time notch display sometime hide/cut your top content.

To prevent this android provides support for this above android pie.

Refer to this document.
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/display-cutouts